# Android image button margin

Tags: android, image, button, margin

So i'm a newbie in android programming and i'm trying to position three image buttons in a row  one next to another.

Problem is I can't get rid of spaces between them and adding *android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"* and *android:layout_marginRight="0dp"* to each one of them doesn't work i guess. I'm using relative layout.

Thx for you help!

Here's XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:src="icon2" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ib_3"
    android:src="icon2" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ib_2"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:src="icon1" />
```

Comment: Post your code. Let us see what you're doing!

Comment: DO you really wana use relative layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tru setting the background of the imagebutton to be null. ImageButtons have a default background that depnds on manufacturer

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_3"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:src="icon2" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_2"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ib_3"
    android:src="icon2" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ib_2"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:src="icon1" />
```